# Pygame mainloop qiuting exception handling

Tags: python, exception, pygame, mainloop

Hi I am writing a simple chess program, unfortunately I have run in some unexpected problems, namely. After I added a list which keeps track of all the figures positions, I cannot close the window using the method which I till now used. which was:

```
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    # print(event)
    # Checking if the user clicks the red quit cross
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # run control the mainloop, wheather True or not 
        run = False
```

After adding the list, this stopped working, so I use now:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # print(event)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.quit()
```

I tried to add some exception handling:

```
try:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
except pygame.error():
    print('Program closed')
```

However the except statement is not reached and an error is printed: (pygame.error: video system not initialized)

Can You please tell me how to handle this exception properly, or suggest a different way of braking the mainloop.

Comment: add `pygame.init()` before you create a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acctually figured it out on my own, so just in case someone is looking for the anwser. The issue was that I was trying to call the redraw function after pygame.display.quit(). Thus after moving both the redraw call and the keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() [wich also utilises the module pygame] the program terminates without any error call. The code should look as follows:

```
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    window_redrawing()

    # Gathering user keyboard input
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # making sure the window can be closed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            run = False

    fig_pos.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the () from the exception catching, namely:
`except pygame.error` instead of `except pygame.error()`

Comment: But this dosen't change anything

Comment: @Mark It does because `pygame.error` is not a function call.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes I understand that what You are saying is right but, it still dosen't sove the problem of a error message being displayed in the console